# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'. Failed to transform neo4j-java-driver-5.12.0.jar

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, neo4j

I have this error when trying to establish a connection between the database and the project in Android Studio. I added the following line in the build.gradle.kts: implementation("org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:5.12.0").
How can i resolved this?

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform neo4j-java-driver-5.12.0.jar (org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:5.12.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\nicol.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.neo4j.driver\neo4j-java-driver\5.12.0\80cf488db020ca5cf8edadb384c1a652e80d33a\neo4j-java-driver-5.12.0.jar.
> > Error while dexing.

I try to add

android {
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
}

but did't work

Comment: Wild guessing here and near to no Android dev experience anymore. Could it be that the required SDK version needs to be much higher (I think I read 34 somewhere) to match the Java 17 requirements of the Java Driver?